# 2D pose estimate button problem

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, ros-electric, 2d-pose-estimate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do the autonomous navigation tutorial I am having problem on "2D Pose Estimate" button in rviz  when i click on it and drag an arrow to set the initial location for turtlebot, the red particles dosen't appears and also location of robot dosen't changes.

fixed frame is set to /map
Target frame is fixed frame

Rviz output:

> [ INFO] [1343324167.032855241]: Setting pose: -0.286 -0.421 -2.323 [frame=/map]

[rviz.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/6iv1l)

[Viewframe.png](http://postimage.org/image/n1dz25bzl/full/)

[rxgraph.png](http://postimage.org/image/nebsrm54r/)

this warring is keep coming up!!

> Node: /move_base Time:
> 1343352282.073253915 Severity: Warn Location:
> /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-navigation-1.6.5/debian/ros-electric-navigation/opt/ros/electric/stacks/navigation/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d_ros.cpp:Costmap2DROS::movementCB:408
> Published Topics: /rosout, /cmd_vel,
> /move_base/current_goal,
> /move_base/goal,
> /move_base/global_costmap/obstacles,
> /move_base/global_costmap/inflated_obstacles,
> /move_base/global_costmap/unknown_space,
> /move_base/global_costmap/robot_footprint,
> /move_base/global_costmap/parameter_descriptions,
> /move_base/global_costmap/parameter_updates,
> /move_base/NavfnROS/plan,
> /move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/obstacles,
> /move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/inflated_obstacles,
> /move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/unknown_space,
> /move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/robot_footprint,
> /move_base/local_costmap/obstacles,
> /move_base/local_costmap/inflated_obstacles,
> /move_base/local_costmap/unknown_space,
> /move_base/local_costmap/robot_footprint,
> /move_base/local_costmap/parameter_descriptions,
> /move_base/local_costmap/parameter_updates, /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan,
> /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/local_plan, /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/cost_cloud, /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/parameter_descriptions,
> /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/parameter_updates,
> /move_base/result,
> /move_base/feedback,
> /move_base/status,
> /move_base/parameter_descriptions,
> /move_base/parameter_updates
> Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration

rosservice call /robot_pose_ekf/get_status

```
status: Input:
 * Odometry sensor
   - is active
   - received 45439 messages
   - listens to topic /odom
 * IMU sensor
   - is active
   - received 45440 messages
   - listens to topic /imu/data
 * Visual Odometry sensor
   - is NOT active
   - received 0 messages
   - listens to topic 
Output:
 * Robot pose ekf filter
   - is active
   - sent 15145 messages
   - pulishes on topics /robot_pose_ekf/odom and /tf
```

rostopic info /particlecloud

```
Type: geometry_msgs/PoseArray

Publishers: 
 * /amcl (http://192.168.0.105:60116/)

Subscribers: 
 * /rviz_1342988348757430620 (http://192.168.0.107:56845/)
 * /rviz_1343351131052484131 (http://192.168.0.107:52481/)
```

Anybody knows how to solve the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39927/2d-pose-estimate-button-problem/) by [Abtin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2687/abtin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason you don't see particles stems from the fact that the particlecloud topic does not appear to be publishing...  Some things to try:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/tmp/my_map.yaml
```

If you followed the tutorials, you've already done that. Other things:

```
rostopic list
```

Edit your question and put the output of the above at the bottom. Also, check for errors in configuration. I'll be more useful after more output...

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0